# Somatória números romanos

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython-notebook

Os números arabes foram já convertidos, porém, em uma lista de strings. Devo fazer a somatória deles.

Exemplo: "10010010010100511"=397

Separar os números

```
`def soma(xkcd):

for c in ["1000", "500", "100", "50", "10", "5", "1"]:
  xkcd = xkcd.replace(c," "+ c)
x= xkcd.split()
valores = [int(val) for val in x]`
```

Aqui tento fazer a soma, porém algo dá errado.

```
`soma=0
for i in range(len(valores)):
for j in range(i+1,len(valores)-1):
    if valores[i] >= valores[j]:
        soma+=i
    else:
        soma-=i`
```

Comment: *"porém algo dá errado"* olá, e já fez debug, olhou o valor das variáveis para identificar o problema?

Comment: Aparentemente é no segundo for, mas não vejo onde tá o erro

Comment: cara, é o seguinte primeiramente eu sugiro dar uma revisada no código que você forneceu aqui, porque na linguagem de programação Python os espaços são significativos e separam blocos logicos de código com o escopo bem definido, da maneira que está organizado não dá pra afirmar nada em relação ao seu código apenas dá pra supor. O erro pode estar no fato de não ter feito a indentação da maneira correta.

Answer (score -3):

Esse é o código todo?

É o que o amigo falou, tenta identar corretamente seu código pra ver se roda direitinho ou pelo menos exibe o que ta errado:

```
def soma(xkcd):

    for c in ["1000", "500", "100", "50", "10", "5", "1"]:
        xkcd = xkcd.replace(c," "+ c)
        x= xkcd.split()
        valores = [int(val) for val in x]

    soma=0
    for i in range(len(valores)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(valores)-1):
            if valores[i] >= valores[j]:
                soma+=i
            else:
                soma-=i
```